# jq - Filtering instances for not contain is not working

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq

I am trying to filter instances within my AWS environment that are currently running. I am using jq to filter the instances:

```
INSTANCE_METADATA=$(aws ec2 --profile $ACCOUNT describe-instances | jq --arg env $ENVIRONMENT '.Reservations|map(select((.Instances[0].Tags[].Value==$env) and (.Instances[0].State.Name=="running") ))')
```

I am then creating a variable for the InstanceIDs:

```
RUNNING_INSTANCE_IDS=$(jq -r '.[].Instances[0].InstanceId' <<<"${BEANSTALK_INSTANCE_METADATA}")
```

This works perfectly fine.

However, there is one instance within the environment that I do not want to include in this list, so I have tried to include another filter within the original jq. I have tried it 2 different ways:

```
$(aws ec2 --profile $ACCOUNT describe-instances | jq --arg env $ENVIRONMENT '.Reservations|map(select((.Instances[0].Tags[].Value==$env) and (.Instances[0].State.Name=="running") and (.Instances[0].Tags[].Value|contains("NFTPerformanceTest")|not)) ))')
```

and

```
$(aws ec2 --profile $ACCOUNT describe-instances | jq --arg env $ENVIRONMENT '.Reservations|map(select((.Instances[0].Tags[].Value==$env) and (.Instances[0].State.Name=="running") and (.Instances[0].Tags[].Value!="NFTPerformanceTest") ))')
```

Neither of these successfully filter out the Instance in question. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you add a relevant extract of the unfiltered `aws` output?

Comment: Consider using the `--query` argument to do the filtering on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you write `.Tags[]`, you are iterating over `.Tags`, so the way you've written the selection criterion cannot achieve the desired effect.

One way to reformulate your query would be to use `any/2` and/or `all/2` as appropriate.  Presumably, for example, the criterion you want based on .Value would be (equivalent to):

```
all(.Instances[0].Tags[].Value; 
    contains("NFTPerformanceTest")|not)
```

### Example

For efficiency, it would make sense to re-order the selection criteria, so you might end up with something like:

```
.Reservations
| map(select(.Instances[0]
             | ( .State.Name=="running" and
                 any(.Tags[]; .Value==$env) and
                 all(.Instances[0].Tags[].Value;
                     contains("NFTPerformanceTest")|not) )))
```